# `sns.scatterplot` subplots like in `sns.catplot`

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot

I'd like to plot only parts of my data in one plot, which is characterised by several values (`environment`, `method`, `charge`).
The plot is supposed to contain two subplots, which show the difference of energy in a changing environment.
I'd like to combine the property of subplots like

```
sns.catplot (data = data, x = 'base', y = 'energy', hue = 'charge', col = 'environment', order = ['A', 'T', 'U1', '', 'G', 'C', 'U2'], jitter = False)
```

allows, but the marker should differ for different `method`s, like this is possible with `sns.scatterplot`.

### MWE

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os

sns.set (style = 'white', color_codes = True, palette = ["#FF0000", "#000FFF", "#00FF00", "#FF8000", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF", "#FFFF00"])
matplotlib.rcParams ['axes.xmargin'] = .1
matplotlib.rcParams ['axes.ymargin'] = .1
matplotlib.spines.rcParams ['axes.spines.right'] = False
matplotlib.spines.rcParams ['axes.spines.top'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams ['xtick.bottom'] = False
matplotlib.rcParams ['ytick.left'] = True

with open (os.path.join (os.environ ['HOME'], 'Data.csv'), 'r') as f :
    data = pd.read_csv (f, index_col = 0, header = head, thousands = None, decimal = '.')
data ['charge'] = data ['charge'].map ({'neu': 'neutral', 'neg': 'negative', 'pos': 'positive'})
data = data.sort_values (['charge', 'base', 'environment'])

Data = sns.scatterplot (data = data, x = 'base', y = 'energy', hue = 'charge', markers = ['o', 'D'], style = 'method', size = 'environment', sizes = [20, 40], legend = 'full')
Data.legend_.set_bbox_to_anchor ( (1, 0.95) )
Data.legend_.set_frame_on (False)
```

### ~/Data.csv

```
,environment,method,base,charge,energy,type
0,acid,pbs,A,neg,0.62561930456411,1
1,acid,pbs,C,neg,0.799621534031657,2
2,acid,pbs,G,neg,0.770572971466597,1
3,acid,pbs,T,neg,0.126584728169651,2
4,acid,pbs,U1,neg,0.374428345935791,2
5,acid,pbs,U2,neg,0.291746197980784,2
6,acid,pbs,A,neu,0.934035994647331,3
7,acid,pbs,C,neu,0.500041130594559,3
8,acid,pbs,G,neu,0.509155630011949,3
9,acid,pbs,T,neu,0.870446169146848,3
10,acid,pbs,U1,neu,0.679180139648077,3
11,acid,pbs,U2,neu,0.84540606157805,3
12,acid,pbs,A,pos,0.803099623249837,2
13,acid,pbs,C,pos,0.21553534776233,2
14,acid,pbs,G,pos,0.934297148023281,2
15,acid,pbs,T,pos,0.900115686005232,2
16,acid,pbs,U1,pos,0.96043715576463,2
17,acid,pbs,U2,pos,0.467469834816884,2
18,acid,polymer,A,neg,0.123150141732642,2
19,acid,polymer,C,neg,0.740518351141596,3
20,acid,polymer,G,neg,0.896777370890702,3
21,acid,polymer,T,neg,0.408044253234988,1
22,acid,polymer,U1,neg,0.292046662445582,3
23,acid,polymer,U2,neg,0.837789816502408,3
24,acid,polymer,A,neu,0.807649576187278,2
25,acid,polymer,C,neu,0.055148858898728,2
26,acid,polymer,G,neu,0.905832437441347,3
27,acid,polymer,T,neu,0.857877607089025,2
28,acid,polymer,U1,neu,0.281146379779226,1
29,acid,polymer,U2,neu,0.090670617828513,3
30,acid,polymer,A,pos,0.66573384402767,1
31,acid,polymer,C,pos,0.32714220531956,3
32,acid,polymer,G,pos,0.323927447775852,1
33,acid,polymer,T,pos,0.958914906565471,2
34,acid,polymer,U1,pos,0.034582851499849,3
35,acid,polymer,U2,pos,0.173906645994618,2
36,base,pbs,A,neg,0.095763807951125,1
37,base,pbs,C,neg,0.906398588118335,2
38,base,pbs,G,neg,0.732348951845637,1
39,base,pbs,T,neg,0.66164731075858,2
40,base,pbs,U1,neg,0.019876194567429,2
41,base,pbs,U2,neg,0.15643168968296,2
42,base,pbs,A,neu,0.919396278242953,3
43,base,pbs,C,neu,0.533476576714686,3
44,base,pbs,G,neu,0.112419635626198,3
45,base,pbs,T,neu,0.368354939760779,3
46,base,pbs,U1,neu,0.652542284929484,3
47,base,pbs,U2,neu,0.925844350236818,3
48,base,pbs,A,pos,0.800861543617807,2
49,base,pbs,C,pos,0.90025035782963,2
50,base,pbs,G,pos,0.745448166571066,2
51,base,pbs,T,pos,0.384651618307524,2
52,base,pbs,U1,pos,0.119021050190697,2
53,base,pbs,U2,pos,0.551899792060278,2
54,base,polymer,A,neg,0.204594409706714,2
55,base,polymer,C,neg,0.52131948722657,3
56,base,polymer,G,neg,0.620951862824387,3
57,base,polymer,T,neg,0.678823614076371,1
58,base,polymer,U1,neg,0.296500456117142,3
59,base,polymer,U2,neg,0.481655237574813,3
60,base,polymer,A,neu,0.080707709861915,2
61,base,polymer,C,neu,0.873990771438981,2
62,base,polymer,G,neu,0.036084629744495,3
63,base,polymer,T,neu,0.930965412264525,2
64,base,polymer,U1,neu,0.236488273835523,1
65,base,polymer,U2,neu,0.356091296689187,3
66,base,polymer,A,pos,0.156807303943183,1
67,base,polymer,C,pos,0.268209514586374,3
68,base,polymer,G,pos,0.632396756390576,1
69,base,polymer,T,pos,0.514567478212226,2
70,base,polymer,U1,pos,0.381917149575242,3
71,base,polymer,U2,pos,0.472816261132487,2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correct, so you use facetgrid and facet on `environment` :

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="environment",sharex=False,sharey=False)
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot,
                x = "base",
                y = "energy",
                hue = "charge",
                style = "method",
                markers = ['o', 'D']
               )
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the legend gets a different formatting somehow. Could you adapt your answer so that the legend (i. e. indentation, sizes of subheadings, …) gets "the default formatting of seaborn" (just like in my MWE)? Is there a short way to take the seaborn style of a legend as default (over the matplotlib settings)?